# Why does firebase encrypt with password hashes instead of storing the hashes?

Tags: passwords, hash, aes

I am trying to migrate off of firebase, as in doing so, you can export the hashes of user passwords. Looking at their algorithm, they do not store password hashes, but rather, they use the first 32-characters of a password hash to encrypt a secret key, and store that instead.

I was mostly wondering, why would they be doing this? Standard practice seems to be to hash with salts, store the result, but they also do this encryption step. Is there any benefit here?

For reference, here is some python code roughly showing the algorithm:

```
intermediary = hashlib.scrypt(password, salt=salt + salt_seperator, n=2**14, r=8, p=1)
signing_key = base64.b64decode(PASSWORD_V2_SIGNING_KEY) # provided by firebase
# encrypt signing_key with the password hash
cipher = AES.new(intermediary[:32], AES.MODE_CTR, initial_value=b'\x00' * 16, nonce=b'')
result = cipher.encrypt(signing_key)
hash_to_store = base64.b64decode(result)
```

Comment: I would guess that this is a way to implement a [pepper](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)).